# Math.h not found even though `-lm` is set

Tags: linux, linker, g++

What causes could there be, that gcc does not link to `math.h` even though I set the flag `-lm`?

```
me@mycomputer$ g++ template_gold.cpp -o template_gold -lm
template_gold.cpp: In function ‘void computeGold(valpoint*, centroid*, int)’:
template_gold.cpp:68: error: ‘max’ was not declared in this scope
template_gold.cpp:70: error: ‘abs’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am sorry, if this is a dupe, but searching the googles and SO I found only post suggesting to set the `-lm`.

***Offending*** Code

```
#include <math.h>
#include "kmeans.h"
extern "C" 
void computeGold( valpoint* h_idata, centroid* h_centroids, int numClusters);
...
for (long valindex = 0; valindex<1024*1024; valindex++)
    {
        minDistance = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        for (k = 0; k<numClusters; k++)
            if (max((long)(h_idata[valindex].value - h_centroids[k].value))<minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = abs((long)(h_idata[valindex].value - h_centroids[k].value));
                myCentroid = k;
            }

        h_idata[valindex].centroid = h_centroids[myCentroid].value;

    }
}
```

Comment: In this code, you seem to be using `-Im` rather than `-lm` ? It should be a lowercase L

Comment: Why do you have `-Im` in the command line rather than `-lm` ? (Not that this is anything to do with your compile errors).

Comment: You need to post the code around lines 65 - 75 and also show what #includes you have

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but that was I type, I corrected. (I even tried -Im, in case I had misread posts...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to use `std::max`, or you forgot adding `using namespace std`. Try

```
void void computeGold(valpoint* ..., centroid* ..., int ...)
{
    using namespace std; /* or using std::max etc. */
}
```

Comment: @Framester It's not that offensive to be honest, although you should include `cmath` instead of `math.h`.

Comment: Mow I get the error`template_gold.cpp:69: error: ‘abs’ is not a member of ‘std’`

Comment: @Framester Did you `include <cmath>` ?